# Import another commit to my repo

Tags: git

Sorry for newbie question but is there a way to import someone else commit (to his own repo) to my repo? it's gonna be a hard thing to change 900+ files manually

Comment: for example i want to use this commit https://github.com/tjstyle/android_kernel_samsung_msm/commit/eba7c736bbf1e0c313efa52e298a2834b1b9b800 ..

Comment: from your link i guess you needed git pull, read the documentation and decide :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a patch file with `git format-patch`  and then apply it to your repo with `git apply patchfile`

Comment: thank you very much! :D you're great. i use this and it works :D

Answer (score 10):

You need to add the other's repo as a remote repo of yours, and fetch its changes:

```
git remote add matefork <github-url>
git fetch matefork
```

Then git knows about the commit, just cherry-pick it with its SHA

```
git cherry-pick <SHA1>
```

Comment: actually i'm little bit confused.. where i do this? from my repo or from the repo i want to import?

Comment: thank you very much for the help.. both your answer and jpa answer work :D