# Git: Import commits from a repo to another repo

Tags: git

I have a big `Git` repository for a project for which I created a plug-in which also is source controller with `Git`. Recently I copied the plug-in's folder to the main project folder. Now I have a project folder source controlled with `Git` and the plug-in's folder which is also source controlled with `Git`. My question is, is there a way to import the commits from the plug-in's repository to the main repository so I can get rid of the plug-in's `.git` folder?

Comment: Some of them or all of them? Do the repos have a common ancestor or are they completely independent?

Comment: The plug-in should have been developed in a branch. Interesting question. Considering how powerful git is, there probably is an answer.

Comment: He can simply export the whole plugin repo as patches and then apply them to the project's repo.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla All of them. The repos don't have a common ancestor, they are completely independent.

Comment: @Vorac I agree, but I didn't know the plug-in would be included in the main project, this is why this situation occurred.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla "He can simply export the whole plugin repo as patches and then apply them to the project's repo". By doing this i would lose the commits which i need :(

Comment: @JasonSwartz: I'm sure git has a feature to export commits as a file which you can then import in another repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import another commit to my repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135943/import-another-commit-to-my-repo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import existing Git repository into another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683531/how-to-import-existing-git-repository-into-another)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Open a command window in the project folder.

Make sure you're on a branch. e.g. `git checkout -b plugin-history`

Add the plugin folder as a remote: `git remote add plugin ../path/to/plugin/repo`

Fetch the hashes from the new remote: `git fetch plugin`

Bulk cherry-pick all the plugin history from the remote branch (see [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) documentation):

```
git cherry-pick firstSha1^..mostRecentSha1
```

(There are more instructions about cherry-picking multiple commits here: [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits))

You should then have all the history as new commits on the plugin-history branch.

Comment: After `git remote add plugin ...` you also need to do `git fetch plugin` otherwise the hashes will not be in your local repository yet.

Comment: @peschü Comments may be removed

Comment: If it is a one time thing then it can be simplified to `git fetch ../path/to/plugin/repo`, `git remote add` is not needed,

Comment: after fetch, I did `git checkout ....` which was easier for me personally. Oh and `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`